# Regex captures all char including char of the succeeding line until a word

Tags: regex

I am trying to get all characters starting from the first line including characters of the succeeding line until I a word `EOL`

Example:

```html
chars here
    chars here
    chars here
EOL
```

Expected output

```html
chars here
    chars here
    chars here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex

```
/.*(?=EOL)/s
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/xC8fE0/2) If you don't have the support for `s` flag, then `/[\s\S]*(?=EOL)/` would work. If you don't have the lookahead support as well, then `(.*)EOL` would work, with the wanted text in Group 1.

Comment: To make it non-greedy you need to change `*` to `*?`, so you get `/.*?(?=EOL/` or `/[\s\S]*?(?=EOL)/`

Comment: @DovGrobgeld Thank you! Amit Joki Thank you very much it works for me :)

Comment: @MVF glad to have helped :O)